# Eclipse code completion failure

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I have been using Eclipse for a few years and everything was fine. But a few days ago, something must have happened, because the code completion broke.

The problem seems to be only related to 1 workspace to a specific project and only to classes from this project.

The suggestions show up just fine, but upon confirming they are not inserted into the code.

I've tried the whole Preferences>...>Advanced to default, closing and opening the project, rebooting Eclipse and switching to a different workspace and back, but the problem persists.

EDIT0: For clarification, autocomplet works fine in another workspace, another project or when using java's own features (such as System.out.println())

EDIT1: Having the error log open, I noticed a new error appearing every time completion failed, here is the full trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ArrayInitializer.traverse(ArrayInitializer.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementNotifier.visitIfNeeded(SourceElementNotifier.java:783)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementNotifier.notifySourceElementRequestor(SourceElementNotifier.java:530)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.CompletionElementNotifier.notifySourceElementRequestor(CompletionElementNotifier.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementNotifier.notifySourceElementRequestor(SourceElementNotifier.java:696)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.CompletionElementNotifier.notifySourceElementRequestor(CompletionElementNotifier.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementNotifier.notifySourceElementRequestor(SourceElementNotifier.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.CompletionElementNotifier.notifySourceElementRequestor(CompletionElementNotifier.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalExtendedCompletionContext.computeEnclosingJavaElements(InternalExtendedCompletionContext.java:158)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalExtendedCompletionContext.getEnclosingElement(InternalExtendedCompletionContext.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalCompletionContext.getEnclosingElement(InternalCompletionContext.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.getEnclosingElement(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.guessParameters(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:325)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.computeGuessingCompletion(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.computeReplacementString(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.getReplacementString(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:332)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.apply(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:388)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaMethodCompletionProposal.apply(JavaMethodCompletionProposal.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.apply(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.apply(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:519)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.apply(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:443)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.insertProposal(CompletionProposalPopup.java:989)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.insertSelectedProposalWithMask(CompletionProposalPopup.java:938)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.verifyKey(CompletionProposalPopup.java:1388)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant$InternalListener.verifyKey(ContentAssistant.java:803)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer$VerifyKeyListenersManager.verifyKey(TextViewer.java:485)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledTextListener.handleEvent(StyledTextListener.java:66)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:802)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKeyDown(StyledText.java:6044)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$7.handleEvent(StyledText.java:5733)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1130)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1126)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1547)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4918)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:364)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4799)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:359)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5110)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2552)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3822)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

EDIT2: I've downloaded a fresh Eclipse, the problem persists, it also seems to apply to classes from a linked library, copying the code to another project doesn't help either.

EDIT3: It suddenly started working again, I have no idea why, I'm unaware of changing anything other than hand-writing more code in my project.

Comment: is you project properly built ?...generally eclipse plugins like code completion rely on the index created out of the build...you should have your code fully built without error to have them work properly

Comment: everything else in the project seems fine, including all the main() classes working (I have multiple related programms in one project, as they are small and plentifull and I don't want my window swamped by projects)

Comment: See if there is anything relevant being written to the error log:
 **Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Error Log**.  A couple of other things to try: [1] Clean and rebuild the project [2] Restart Eclipse with the **-clean** parameter. (I doubt if those measures will fix your problem but they can't do any harm, and the testing would only take a couple of minutes so you lose nothing by trying.)

Comment: I seem to have found something that might be relevant, no idea what to do with it